# make the program printing thing based on the output you give to him

Tags: python

Yap I dunno why it does not work

```
sassa = input('Hi dave\n')
sassi = 111

if sassa == sassi:
  print ("rocks")
```

Comment: `sassa` is a string but `sassi` is an int. Use `int()` to convert the string to an int.

Answer (score 2):

`input` returns a `str` so you would want to compare it to a string

```
sassa = input('Hi dave\n')
sassi = '111'

if sassa == sassi:
  print ("rocks")
```

Or convert your input to an `int`

```
sassa = int(input('Hi dave\n'))
sassi = 111

if sassa == sassi:
  print ("rocks")
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the types match. So, you need to convert `sassa` to an int before comparing like so:

```
sassa = input('Hi dave\n')
sassi = 111

if int(sassa) == sassi:
  print ("rocks")
```

Answer (score 0):

It do not work because the input return a string.
So if you type 111, the data will be saved as the string "111". To make it work you can change sassi to

```
sassi = "111"
```

Or you can convert the input string to number before comparing:

```
sassa = int(input('Hi dave\n'))
```